# How to regenerate token in Android GraphQL?

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql

What is the better approach to regenerate the JWT token using refresh token in Apollo Graphql in Andriod Kotlin?.

Now we are using an Auth interceptor that extends ApolloInterceptor to attach the JWT token in the request header.

I want to check whether the Toke expires from here and it should call another mutation to generate a new token. Then it should proceed with the previous call with the new token.

Please refer to the code below

```
  class AuthInterceptor(private val jwtToken: String) : ApolloInterceptor {
        override fun interceptAsync(
            request: ApolloInterceptor.InterceptorRequest,
            chain: ApolloInterceptorChain,
            dispatcher: Executor,
            callBack: ApolloInterceptor.CallBack
        ) {
            val header = request.requestHeaders.toBuilder().addHeader(
                HEADER_AUTHORIZATION,
                "$HEADER_AUTHORIZATION_BEARER $jwtToken"
            ).build()
            chain.proceedAsync(request.toBuilder().requestHeaders(header).build(), dispatcher, callBack)
        }
    
        override fun dispose() {}
    
        companion object {
            private const val HEADER_AUTHORIZATION = "Authorization"
            private const val HEADER_AUTHORIZATION_BEARER = "Bearer"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Apollo Android Client V3 and Using Kotlin Coroutine then use Apollo Runtime Dependency and Try `HttpInterceptor` instead of `ApolloInterceptor`. I think this is the better/best approach. For Reference [Click Here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/kotlin/advanced/authentication#authenticating-your-http-requests-with-apollo-httpinterceptor)

In your app-level `build.gradle` file

```
plugins {
......
    id("com.apollographql.apollo3").version("3.5.0")
.....
}

dependencies {
  implementation("com.apollographql.apollo3:apollo-runtime")
}
```

Now write your interceptor for the Apollo client.

FYI: If you've added the `Authorization` header using Interceptor or using `addHttpHeader` in client already then remove it or don't add header here `val response = chain.proceed(request.newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token").build())`, just build the request. Otherwise `Authorization` header will add multiple times in the request. So, be careful.

```
class AuthorizationInterceptor @Inject constructor(
    val tokenRepo: YourTokenRepo
) : HttpInterceptor {
      private val mutex = Mutex()
    
      override suspend fun intercept(request: HttpRequest, chain: HttpInterceptorChain): HttpResponse {
        var token = mutex.withLock {
          // get current token
        }
    
        val response = chain.proceed(request.newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token").build())
    
        return if (response.statusCode == 401) {
          token = mutex.withLock {
            // get new token from your refresh token API
          }
          chain.proceed(request.newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $token").build())
        } else {
          response
        }
      }
    }
```

Configure your Apollo client like below.

```
ApolloClient.Builder()
            .httpServerUrl(BASE_GRAPHQL_URL)
            .webSocketServerUrl(BASE_GRAPHQL_WEBSOCKET_ENDPOINT) // if needed
            .addHttpHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .addHttpHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHttpHeader("User-Agent", userAgent)
            .addHttpInterceptor(AuthorizationInterceptor(YourTokenRepo))
            .httpExposeErrorBody(true)
            .build()
```